Hi everyone. I would appreciate some help with this question: Let X~Normal(0,1) and define $Y:=X\cdot\mathbf{1}_{|X|>2}$. Find the CDF of Y.
This is my working below, please could you help me see if it is correct, or where I went wrong :) https://i.sstatic.net/MBSjhyjp.jpg Thank you!

You need to reconsider your $-2\le y\le 2$ range. Hint: y can only take the value $0$ in this interval.

Please don’t use
images instead of typing your formulas + https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

From How to ask a good question: Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.
